# Fetch a file from google docs programmatically

Tags: objective-c, svn, google-api-objc-client

I want to let the user access his/her document from the google docs in my application. After this the file will be sent to the web services by converting the file into bytes.

I searched about it and found that Gdrive apis are there and tried to download the library and ran the command " svn checkout http://google-api-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ google-api-objectivec-client-read-only
" on the terminal. But, I got following error:

Fingerprint: ce:67:99:25:2c:ac:78:12:7d:94:b5:62:2c:31:c5:16:a6:34:73:53
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? accept (p)ermanently
svn: warning: Error handling externals definition for 'google-api-objectivec-client-read-only/Source/JSON':
svn: warning: OPTIONS of 'https://github.com/stig/json-framework.git/tags/v2.3.2/Classes': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://github.com)

Kindly guide me if these apis let the user access the files from the google doc? If yes then please help me out in removing this error. Or, is there any other method with the help of which the user will be able to access his/her files. I have heard about dropbox api but my client is not in its favour.

Comment: This looks like a library checkout issue not a Drive SDK issue.

Comment: Is there any sample tutorial which has used this library. So that i can import that library in my project or any other location from which i can download this library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it flashes following in the terminal " Fingerprint: ce:67:99:25:2c:ac:78:12:7d:94:b5:62:2c:31:c5:16:a6:34:73:53 (R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? accept (p)permanently  "

Then type p (p for permanently) in the terminal. It will work